# Displaying data on an laretdialog using titanium and remote database

Tags: titanium

i'm developping a mobile app using titanium appcelerator. in my app i have a tableview contains list of persons' name retrieved from remote database. when i click on each row of my tableview, i want to display some other data from remote database (the activity of each person of my list). i used a php web services to do this. i used a loop "For" to display data, but the problem that when i click on a row all data (all activity of persons are displayed). i tried to do this whitout loop, i can display now only one data (on click, only the activity of the first person is displayed for all rows of my tableview). i do not know what exacly should i put as condition or witch loop must be used for this.
Any help please. this is a screenshot of my tableview and the alert dialog: https://www.dropbox.com/s/osan0bb4i6s2bqd/scrennShot.png

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the click EventListner to TableView..
Hope it will works for you...
and Pass the data object to TableRow when its created

```js
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
   height : Ti.UI.Size,             
   left : 0,
   obj : your_data[i] // From the array etc for specific row .
});
```

Add EventListner

```js
e.rowData.obj;
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, that exactly what i want to do ! it works fine now :)